# call stack is lost during debug in xcode with iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, callstack

I create a simple test app which contains a table view, I can select one of rows in the table,

```
- (void) __attribute__((noinline)) A
{

}
- (void) __attribute__((noinline)) B
{
    [self A];
}
- (void) __attribute__((noinline)) C
{
    [self B];
}
- (void) __attribute__((noinline)) D
{
    [self C];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
#pragma unused(tableView, indexPath)
    [self D];
}
```

when I debug this function, I set a breakpoint at C, then the call stack only contains C, D does not appear. then I set a breakpoint at B, then only B shows up, C and D disappeared.

It's a release build, which contains lots of compiler options, since It's legacy, I dont know which compiler options/parameters can cause this. Is there any one know this? Thanks.

Update:
1. I can see these four functions with nm command, so they are not inlined.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it's a release build it's optimized, and likely the calls are inlined.  So no stack frames for the intermediate methods.

Comment: update the post. with  __attribute__((noinline)) it still does not work

Comment: Even if the calls are not literally inlined, if there is nothing to execute following the call the compiler may do "transfer control" rather than "call" -- no stack push.

Comment: even I can see these functions with nm commands? the more weird thing is: in my real case, after my function is called, the whole call stack only contains that function frame, all other frames are gone. that's not inline for sure.

Comment: Insert some code after the calls.

Comment: I am sure it is related with optimization, But I dont know which optimization it is and whether we can disable it when compiling with -Os

Comment: Did the code you inserted actually do something.  It needs to, eg, update a static, so that it has side-effects and can't be eliminated.